# Blazor not discovering new pages in subfolders

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I create a new page, e.g. in Pages/Clients/ subfolder with following code:

```
@page "/clients"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<div>My clients page</div>
```

I put the link:

```
<NavLink href="/clients" class="nav-link">Clients</NavLink>
```

When I click on link the page shows me default message

> Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

Then I stop the app. Put my clients page in "Pages" folder. Run the application and I see the proper page  with

> My clients page

Ok, then I move my page file again to Pages/Clients/ subfolder, run the app and... it still works! Moreover - If I do any changes to Clients.razor page it is being shown correctly in browser.

So it looks like Blazor cannot find the page in subfolder for the first time, but after it "registers" it somehow it could find and show it correctly all the time.

I have the

```
<base href="~/" />
```

line in my _Host.cshtml file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I was fighting with it for a couple of days and right after posting on Stackoverflow I accidentally found an answer.
In your .csproj file there were following lines:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Watch Include="**\*.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Pages\Activities\ActivitiesList.razor" />
    <Content Remove="Pages\Entrance\Entrance.razor" />
    <Content Remove="Pages\Instructors\InstructorsList.razor" />
    <Content Remove="Pages\Plan\Plan.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Pages\Activities\ActivitiesList.razor" />
    <None Include="Pages\Administration\Administration.razor" />
    <None Include="Pages\Entrance\Entrance.razor" />
    <None Include="Pages\Instructors\InstructorsList.razor" />
    <None Include="Pages\Plan\Plan.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Watch Remove="Pages\Activities\ActivitiesList.razor" />
    <Watch Remove="Pages\Administration\Administration.razor" />
    <Watch Remove="Pages\Entrance\Entrance.razor" />
    <Watch Remove="Pages\Instructors\InstructorsList.razor" />
    <Watch Remove="Pages\Plan\Plan.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I removed most of them and left only this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Watch Include="**\*.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

All the files are being now discovered correctly. Just remember to check your csproj if some garbage aren't being generated there during development process.

Comment: Is this .NET 5 release candidate 1? or .NET Core 3.*?

Comment: This is .Net Core 3.1

Comment: This is still an issue in .NET 6  / Visual Studio 2022. Unbelievable. This has cost my team probably multiple days of combined time. Thanks so much for the answer.  Is there a place somewhere where I can upvote this as a serious problem?

Comment: You can create an issue in github repo of ASP.NET Core: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy. Why did Visual Studio add those to the .csproj?

Comment: Has anyone found out why this is happening? Every time I add a new .razor page I have to go remove these entries.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I also had to restart VS, Just updating the project file did not fix it straight away.

Comment: Still an issue in .NET 7 / VS 2022

Answer (score 0):

With [asp.net-core-7.0](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-7.0) this is still an issue.

I did the following

```
dotnet new webapp
```

I added a folder `Orders` and two files below it like this

```
     -- Pages --
           |
           |-- Index.cshtml
           |
           |-- Orders --
                   |
                   |--- EditOrder.cshtml
                   |
                   |--- EditOrder.cshtml.cs
```

Inside `Index.cshtml` i added a link like this

```cs
 <a type="button" 
    asp-page="/Orders/EditOrder" 
    asp-route-Orderid="@order.OrderId"  
    asp-route-returnId="-1">@order.OrderId</a></td>
```

To make it work i had to add this to my project file `HelloWorld.csproj`

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Pages\Orders\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Scanning through some pages from the [aspnet-core overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/introduction-to-aspnet-core?view=aspnetcore-7.0) i still could not find any information about the needed settings for subfolders.
If anyone has a link to the docs please add a comment.